# django mail works, but not with celery

Tags: django, email, celery

I'm really confused. I was able to configure sending e-mails with django:

models:

```
send_mail_notification(...)
```

tasks:

```
def send_mail_notification(...):
    (...)
    send_mail(subject, message, fromname, tolist, fail_silently=False)
```

This works. It sends the e-mail and I receive it. But now I want celery to do it asynchronously:

models:

```
send_mail_notification.apply_async((...), countdown=5)
```

tasks:

```
@shared_task
def send_mail_notification(...):
    (...)
    send_mail(subject, message, fromname, tolist, fail_silently=False)
```

What is strange here is that celery is not giving me any error. It says the task succeeded, but I never get those e-mails, it just prints them:

```
[2014-01-18 08:12:12,202: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: mydjangoapp.tasks.send_mail_notification[2dbb5d74-2002-4948-b627-cf3630d1681b] eta:[2014-01-18 08:12:17.184785+00:00]
[2014-01-18 08:12:18,031: WARNING/Worker-1] Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Match notification
From: fromname
To: myemail@gmail.com
Date: Sat, 18 Jan 2014 08:12:18 -0000
Message-ID: <20140118081218.62652.73949@mycomputer>

(... message body ...)
[2014-01-18 08:12:18,032: WARNING/Worker-1] -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2014-01-18 08:12:18,034: INFO/MainProcess] Task mydjangoapp.tasks.send_mail_notification[e9450ef8-8c9a-4179-98c9-b5cd07e6ffc7] succeeded in 0.00458826124668s: None
```

What's going on here?

Comment: I don't know the details of the django send_mail functionality, but are you sure it's connecting to the smtp server? That it's the right server and that the server is delivering mail?

Comment: Are you using RabbitMQ or the django development version of celery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What returns [`django.core.email.get_connection`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#django.core.mail.get_connection) when called from `send_mail_notification`? And what happens when you specify `connection` in `send_mail`, i. e:

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection, send_mail

conn = get_connection(backend='django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend')
send_mail(subject, message, fromname, tolist, fail_silently=False, connection=conn)
```

Maybe Celery has different email backend?

Comment: Yup.. that was it. In my app the email backend is determined by the environment variable DEBUG. What was happening was that I was running the web server from an environment with DEBUG=False and Celery was running frmo an environment with DEBUG=True, and so was using the console as email backend instead. Amazing!